# How Do I Simplify "expect(typeof x).toBe(typeof new Class)"

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'd like to check that something is a type in a jest test with typescript. Any ideas?

```
expect(typeof controller.presenter).toBe(typeof new CheckboxPresenter(null))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.toBeInstanceOf()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobeinstanceofclass) Jest matcher:

```
expect(controller.presenter).toBeInstanceOf(CheckboxPresenter)
```

Comment: lol, didn't find that one, looking for type everywhere there ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to say something like

```
controller.presenter instanceof CheckboxPresenter
```

See the [MDN instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator

this would return a boolean, so you could write it like

```
expect( controller.presenter instanceof CheckboxPresenter ).toBeTrue();
```

Some documentation is also available on [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) on the [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) documentation site.